# Conditional to open Intent based off Uri

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm attempting to make it so if the user clicks the Share button, and no image exists in the uri then the intent doesn't get launched (preventing nullexception crash).

Otherwise, continue with allowing to share intent.

```
case R.id.meetBtn: 

                Uri photoUri = Uri.parse(sImage.toString());

                if (photoUri != null || sImage.toString() != null || sImage.toString() != "")
                {
                    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    shareIntent.setData(photoUri);
                    shareIntent.setType("image/png");
                    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, photoUri);
                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Use this for sharing"));
                }

                break;
            }
```

As you see I tried a few diff things, but still launching with crash.

Comment: Exactly what error are you getting? My initial guess is that sImage itself is null, and so you're getting a NullPointerException before you even get to your if. But that's really just a guess, without further information. If it that is the case, then you need "if (sImage != null)" before the Uri.parse call. Also, your "if" conditions are all or'd together, instead of and'ed, so they all be evaluated, which is really unlikely to be what you actually want.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest a Try-Catch block rather than an if statement.

```
try {
     [insert code here]
    } catch (Exception e) {
     [Log Error or create error toast]
}
```

I'd suggest going with a more specific error catch, however that is the basic necessary structure.

More details on try-catch blocks are at these links:
[Avoid try/catch on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4575736/throws-try-and-catch-on-android)

For the official documentation

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/try.html - follow the catch and finally links from there as well.

Comment: Not sure how this would help considering I'm using the if conditional to specifically check if there is a picture loaded in my current ImageView (which is first taken from camera, and stored externally).

Comment: A try-catch block breaks the moment the chosen Exception is caught, ceasing to call any further code.
However, if you want to continue using an if statement, you could try:
if (photoUri.toString().isEmpty())
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty%28%29 for more details on that.